# Custom For Loop in Python

Tags: python

Is there any pythonic way to do the same as code bellow, but in a pythonic way?

I created this code for web scraping a website, but I think there should be a better way for adding the contents to lists other than repeating the same code for each element.

here are the lists i will add elements to:

```
Proporcao_de_Sobras = []
liq_dir =[]
liq_sobras=[]
liq_reservas=[]
Encerramento=[]
n_emissao =[]
tp_ofert =[]
inv_minimo =[]
```

And here is the code I am using to add the elements to lists.

```
try:
    for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[*]/td/span[2]'):
        Proporcao_de_Sobras.append(x.text)
except:
    pass

try:
    for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[*]/td/span[4]'):
        liq_dir.append(x.text)
except:
    pass

try:
    for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[*]/td/span[6]'):
        liq_sobras.append(x.text)
except:
    pass

try:
    for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[*]/td/span[8]'):
        liq_reservas.append(x.text)
except:
    pass

try:
    for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[*]/td/span[10]'):
        Encerramento.append(x.text)
except:
    pass

try:
    for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[*]/td/span[12]'):
        n_emissao.append(x.text)
except:
    pass

try:
    for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[*]/td/span[14]'):
        tp_ofert.append(x.text)
except:
    pass

try:
    for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[*]/td/span[16]'):
        inv_minimo.append(x.text)
except:
    pass
```

This goes on for more 5 or 6 times.

Comment: You can do a list of your lists `[Proporcao_de_Sobras, liq_dir, ...]` and iterate over it. And you can use their index to set your `x` value in `span[x]`. Using `x = index*2 + 2`. You can get index using `enumerate()`

Comment: `except: pass` **will** bite you at some point and waste much time.  Happens to everyone. If you have reasons to believe some exception(s) may be thrown, specify ex:  `except KeyError, IndexError): pass`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another pythonic way using dictionaries:

```py
def get_data(your_lists):
    data = {}
    for list_index, list_name in enumerate(your_lists):
        try:
            data[list_name] = [x for x in find_elements_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[*]/td/span[{(list_index + 1) * 2}]')]
        except:
            pass
    return data

your_lists = ['Proporcao_de_Sobras', 'liq_dir', 'loq_reservas', 'Encerramento', 'n_emissao', 'tp_ofert', 'inv_minimo']

all_data = get_data(your_lists)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pythonic way N1, using mutability of lists:

```
def get_text(x_path, dest_list):
    for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(x_path):
        dest_list.append(x.text)

Proporcao_de_Sobras = []
get_text('//*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[*]/td/span[2]', Proporcao_de_Sobras)
```

Pythonic way N2, using dicts:

```
paths = {
    '//*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[*]/td/span[2]': [],
    '//*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[*]/td/span[4]': [],
    ....
}

for k, v in paths.items():
    for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(k):
        v.append(x.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function for it. I would advise to catch specific exceptions though.

```
def fill_elem(fill_list, xpath):
    try:
        for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
            fill_list.append(x.text)
    except SomeException:
        pass
    else:
        return fill_list

proporcao_de_sobras = []
proporcao_de_sobras = fill_elem(proporcao_de_sobras, r'//*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr[*]/td/span[2]')
```